# random sampling with Pandas data frame disjoint groups

Tags: python, pandas, disjoint-sets

I need to randomly separate a data frame into two disjoint sets by the attribute `'ids'`. For example, consider the following data frame:

```
df=
Out[470]: 
          0     1     2     3       ids
0      17.0  18.0  16.0  15.0      13.0
1      18.0  16.0  15.0  15.0      13.0
2      16.0  15.0  15.0  16.0      13.0
131    12.0   8.0  21.0  19.0      14.0
132     8.0  21.0  19.0  20.0      14.0
133    21.0  19.0  20.0   9.0      14.0
248     NaN   NaN  12.0  11.0      17.0
249     NaN  12.0  11.0  10.0      17.0
250    12.0  11.0  10.0   NaN      17.0
287     3.0   3.0   1.0   8.0      20.0
288     3.0   1.0   8.0   3.0      20.0
289     1.0   8.0   3.0   3.0      20.0
413    21.0   7.0  16.0  18.0      25.0
414     7.0  16.0  18.0  19.0      25.0
415    16.0  18.0  19.0  18.0      25.0
665    10.0   8.0   8.0   7.0      27.0
666     8.0   8.0   7.0   9.0      27.0
667     8.0   7.0   9.0   8.0      27.0
790     NaN   NaN  15.0   NaN      33.0
791     NaN  15.0   NaN  10.0      33.0
792    15.0   NaN  10.0   NaN      33.0
812     NaN  16.0   NaN  17.0      34.0
813    16.0   NaN  17.0   NaN      34.0
814     NaN  17.0   NaN  13.0      34.0
944     3.0   4.0   3.0  18.0      35.0
945     4.0   3.0  18.0  18.0      35.0
946     3.0  18.0  18.0  11.0      35.0
1059    9.0  10.0   3.0   4.0      56.0
1060   10.0   3.0   4.0   3.0      56.0
1061    3.0   4.0   3.0   3.0      56.0
    ...   ...   ...   ...       ...
10125   NaN   9.0   5.0   5.0  101317.0
10126   9.0   5.0   5.0   5.0  101317.0
10127   5.0   5.0   5.0   7.0  101317.0
```

I need to get two (randomly separated with some fraction size) dataframes with **no** intersecting values of `ids`.

I know how to solve it in 'non-pandasian' way:

- get the unique values of the `ids`
- randomly split the unique values into two disjoint groups
- select row according to values of `ids` in two groups using `.isin()`

I am wondering whether there is a simple and neat way to do it with some pandas built-in function, like `.sample()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html) to perform the split:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

# Initialize the GroupShuffleSplit.
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.5)

# Get the indexers for the split.
idx1, idx2 = next(gss.split(df, groups=df.ids))

# Get the split DataFrames.
df1, df2 = df.iloc[idx1], df.iloc[idx2]
```

Comment: this is indeed very nice method - i've never used it before. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

```
df1 = df.sample(frac=1).loc[df.ids % 2 == 0]
df2 = df.loc[df.index.difference(df1.index)]
```

---

**OLD** incorrect (it doesn't care of separating IDs) answer:

you can first shuffle your DF using `sample(frac=1)` and then use [np.split()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
df1, df2 = np.split(df.sample(frac=1), 2)
```

Comment: @MaxU, thanks, but it does not work. I get the same 'ids' in both sets.

Comment: Great! Works as charm! (I'm learning Pandas, so such neat solutions are very valued)

Comment: @ArnoldKlein, glad i could help :-)

Comment: This isn't really random though, as `df1` will always have even ids, and `df2` will always have odd ids.  Depending on how the ids were generated this could introduce bias.  It's also dependent on there being a similar distribution of even and odd ids.

Comment: @MaxU, sorry, but root's answers is better. thank you.

Comment: @ArnoldKlein, I agree. I think his answer better than mine